# Writing data to I/O address

Tags: delphi, io

i have a device (cash drawer) and i would like to directly communicate with the device. I know that its on address f1. Also openbit is 01.

As i've understood so far, i'd need to send 1 to memory address f1 and the cash drawer should open. Though using asm, i get access violation. Then again i've read that windows does not let you communicate directly to device i/o addresses (need to use win). What would be the correct way to send the data to that address.
Note that i cannot use drivers, because i can't communicate with the driver inside my application.
Op. system is win7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So far as I know, the only way for a user space app to communicate with a device is via a driver.

Comment: I doubt it's actually at "memory address F1" but is instead at I/O PORT F1. The difference is the IN and OUT instructions are used for I/O port access and not MOV etc. A driver and supporting Delphi example is available here: (http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/Delphi/iopm/index.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a library called inpout32.dll that allowed direct port access you can find it here

http://logix4u.net/Inpout32.dll_Discussion/write_DELPHI_for_inpout32.dll.html

But i don't know if supports windows 7.

Comment: Looks like there are people using inout32.dll on Windows 7 out there on the web. Just do a search.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent suggestions above, check out [this delphi code for writing and reading I/O](http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/Delphi/iopm/index.htm). We have used the GWIOPM to do what you are asking, but note that it will be ok for 32-bit versions of Windows up to W7 etc (as is the case for most 'free' drivers). For 64-bit Windows you need a signed kernel driver. For this there are few things available at the moment. We had to write our own.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you communicate with the driver from your application? It's the best way for ring 3 application to talk with hardware in a safe manner.

However, if you really insist using drivers, you can try going to ring 0 and do direct access. It's much harder than in previous Windows versions (XP and before) but it's possible. I haven't done it myself since I don't have Windows 7, but you can try asking in asm programming forum anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not believe that you can enter ring 0 from user mode. Only the kernel can do that.

Comment: if you're good enough at asm, yes you can. my friend is really good at it and he's capable of doing that. at least he shows me on windows xp.