# Writing to an I/O Address

Tags: c

I am using a [VersaLogic Osprey Board](https://www.versalogic.com/Products/Manuals/MEPU3311_PRM.pdf) and I am running Lubuntu 16.04 Xenial with GCC compiler 6.2.0. Writing in C, I cannot compile C++.

I am trying to read from the I/O address of the Watchdog timer, with the intent of later enabling it. According to the [data sheet](https://www.versalogic.com/Products/Manuals/MEPU3311_PRM.pdf) the I/O address is 1CA8 (WDT_CTL is the identifier of this address)

The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
#define WDT_CTL 0x1CA8

int main(void)
{

char *p_CTL = (char*) WDT_CTL;

printf("Attempting to print contents %c\n"),*p_CTL); 


}
```

The code compiles, but I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I get to the important line, there are no other errors or warnings. As far as I know a seg fault is a "you can't access that memory location" error, but I am trying to read from the address that I found in the data sheet.

I have done some research and according to the datasheet the address I have is an I/O address, which seems to be different from a normal address. When I look at the address of a custom variable (char a) that address is 12 digits long as opposed to the four I am given for the watchdog timer.

Am I missing something? Is it a limitation of Lubuntu that I can no longer write directly to an I/O address? Do I need to use some specific command to do so? Do I need to enable something or change a setting?

Note that this thread is different from one with a [similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898915/writing-data-to-i-o-address) because that was done in Windows 7, not Lubuntu and that fix will not work here.

Comment: Is this userspace or kernel space? Because Virtual addresses would prevent you from accessing physical addresses.
Look at your `/dev` directory and `/sys/bus` and see if you can find the peripheral in question there...

Comment: I have done nothing fancy, and this code was written in a leafpad on the desktop. So I assume it is userspace.
When I look in /dev I see a lot of ttyxx and ttySxx, but no WDT or watchdog. I am unsure of how to figure out what these tty things are as I cannot cd into them or sudo leafpad them open.It is a similar story for /sys/bus

Comment: When they say this is an "I/O Address" do they say that the I/O is *memory mapped*? If not, then the I/O address may represent an I/O port, not a memory mapped address.

Comment: The manual says it's I/O mapped, not memory mapped. You cannot access it through memory. There is usually a special library from the manufacturer for controlling the board.

Comment: Google "linux inp out instructions", the first hit looks pretty good.

Comment: Typically, such I/O activity is performed by a driver that has sufficient privilege to run the required instructions and access the hardware register addresses. Don't try it in user space.

Comment: With all this being said: how do I go about using this Watchdog timer?

Comment: Please quote the documentation you are referring to. In my experience memory-mapped IO areas are on higher addresses, something like 0xffff1ca8. Which makes me think that you have mistaken an offset for a complete address. Reread the docu and look for keywords like "base address", "IO area start address", "peripheral address block". If you find such, add it to the 0x1ca8.

Comment: @Yunnosch, The link has been added under the hotlink "Data Sheet." I have not mistaken an offset for an address. The shortness of the I/O address they gave makes me suspicious

Comment: Can your access method be used to write to any other FPGA register? Or at least to any other IO register? I.e. is it only this register which causes the problem or does the same problem occur with other registers?

Comment: @Yunnosch I cannot access any of the IO registers and I do not know why or how to fix it.

Comment: It turns out the physical Watchdog timer was on a peripheral board I replaced with a custom board. I had no way of knowing this, as Versalogic doesn't publish this information.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually access the watchdog hardware:

This has worked on several different computers.

```
#include "watchdog.h"
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open() */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* write() */
#include <string.h>     /* strerror() */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno */

#define APP_VERSION     "1.1.0"

/* Look for the device in two places */
#define WD_KICK_DEV_NAME_1       "/dev/cs5535/gpio/5"
#define WD_KICK_DEV_NAME_2       "/dev/gpio/5"

#define WD_ENABLE_DEV_NAME_1     "/dev/cs5535/gpio/27"
#define WD_ENABLE_DEV_NAME_2     "/dev/gpio/27"

#define TEXT_WDOG_KICK           "Ot0101"
#define TEXT_WDOG_ENABLE         "1TO"
#define TEXT_WDOG_DISABLE        "0TO"

static INT32 wd_kick_fd;
static INT32 wd_enable_fd;


/**
 * Return the version
 */
const char *wd_get_version(void)
{
   return(APP_VERSION);
}


/**
 * Open GPIO-5 and GPIO-27
 */
INT32 wd_init(void)
{
   if (((wd_kick_fd = open(WD_KICK_DEV_NAME_2, O_WRONLY)) < 0) &&
       ((wd_kick_fd = open(WD_KICK_DEV_NAME_1, O_WRONLY)) < 0))
   {
      printf("Failed to open '%s' or '%s': %s (%d)\n",
             WD_KICK_DEV_NAME_1, WD_KICK_DEV_NAME_2, strerror(errno), errno);
      return(FAILURE);
   }

   if (((wd_enable_fd = open(WD_ENABLE_DEV_NAME_2, O_WRONLY)) < 0) &&
       ((wd_enable_fd = open(WD_ENABLE_DEV_NAME_1, O_WRONLY)) < 0))
   {
      printf("Failed to open '%s' or '%s': %s (%d)\n",
             WD_ENABLE_DEV_NAME_1, WD_ENABLE_DEV_NAME_2, strerror(errno), errno);
      return(FAILURE);
   }
   return(SUCCESS);
}


/**
 * Disabled via GPIO-27
 */
void wd_disable(void)
{
   (void)write(wd_enable_fd, TEXT_WDOG_DISABLE, strlen(TEXT_WDOG_DISABLE));
}


/**
 * Enabled via GPIO-27
 */
void wd_enable(void)
{
   (void)write(wd_enable_fd, TEXT_WDOG_ENABLE, strlen(TEXT_WDOG_ENABLE));
}

/**
 * Kick the watchdog by toggling GPIO 5
 */
void wd_kick(void)
{
   (void)write(wd_kick_fd, TEXT_WDOG_KICK, strlen(TEXT_WDOG_KICK));
}
```

and the `watchdog.h` file contains:

```
#ifndef WATCHDOG_H_INCLUDED
#define WATCHDOG_H_INCLUDED


/**
 * Grab the version of the kicker stuff
 */
const char *wd_get_version(void);


/**
 * Do any initialization needed for the watchdog.
 *
 * @return SUCCESS or FAILURE
 */
INT32 wd_init(void);


/**
 * Disables the watchdog.
 * If watchdog cannot be disabled, then calls wd_kick()
 */
void wd_disable(void);


/**
 * Enables the watchdog.
 * If watchdog cannot be disabled, do nothing.
 */
void wd_enable(void);


/**
 * Kicks the watchdog
 */
void wd_kick(void);


#endif /* WATCHDOG_H_INCLUDED */
```